# Securing one single WMS layer on GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wms, security

My aim is to secure one specific layer (ex. topp:states) with username and password.

I tried a couple of combinations in the `layer.properties` file.

`*.*.r=*
*.*.w=GROUP_ADMIN,ADMIN
topp.states.r=ROLE_WS
mode=HIDE`

This somehow secures the layer `topp:states` but I can't access it using the role `ROLE_WS` (which has the user I want to give access to the layer to).

Comment: Have you tried to add this security feature via the geoserver web admin page?

Comment: Tried both. Same results. I was wondering if there are any extra steps required?